# Desplazar elementos dentro de una matriz de dimension X por X. Java

Tags: java, matrices

Llevo tiempo dandole vueltas a este caso, a ver si desde la comunidad podeís echarme una mano. Gracias de antemano.

Supongamos que tenemos una matriz de enteros de dimension X por X. Por ejemplo:
int matrix={0,5,0,0} , {0,0,5,5} , {5,5,5,0}, {5,0,0,0}};

El caso es que querría desplazar los 5 hacia la derecha sin que se sumasen, es decir, desplazar los valores de 0 a un lado y los no ceros a otro. Mi matriz quedaría de la siguiente forma:

matrix={0,0,0,5} , {0,0,5,5} , {0,5,5,5} ,{0,0,0,5}}

El problema que tengo es cuando se juntan dos valores que no sean ceros.
Lo que hice fue dos búcle for aninado para intentar resolverlo, pero en todos los casos no funciona, puesto que está el problema de que se encuentren dos valores seguidos y al ser la dimension metida por el usuario, no se como realizarlo.

```
public void compactar() {
        for(int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j< matrix[i].length-1;j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] !=0 && matrix[i][j+1] == 0) {
                    matrix[i][j+1]= matrix[i][j];
                    matrix[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿La matriz siempre tiene ceros y números mayores a ceros iguales? , En tu ejemplo de matriz hay ceros y el número 5 ¿podrían haber otros números en la misma fila,, es decir, podría haber una  fila como esta: ` (0,6,5,0)`?

Comment: Así es, podría haber valores distintos de 5.

Comment: Ok. Puse mi respuesta. Mi pregunta fue porque en caso de valores iguales, entonces, hubiera utilizado un ` Sort ` y el código hubiera sido pequeño. Salvo que no te interese el orden de los números después de pasar los ceros delante entonces, el `Sort` lo simplifica.

Answer (score 1):

**EDICION:** Esta edición la pongo primera puesto esta vinculada al problema en si. Estuviste el el camino. Aquí te dejo el código corregido, analizarlo. Luego añado mayor detalle.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] matrix={{5,0,0,5},{0,0,6,5},{5,5,5,0},{0,0,0,5}};
        for(int i=0; i<matrix[0].length; i++) 
       {     
          for(int y=0;y<matrix[0].length-1; y++) 
       {

            for(int j=0;j<matrix[0].length -y-1;j++) 
            {  
              if(matrix[i][j]> matrix[i][j+1] 
                 && (matrix[i][j]== 0 || matrix[i][j+1]==0)  )            
                {
                    int temp = matrix[i][j]; 
                    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j+1]; 
                     matrix[i][j+1] = temp; 
                  } 
            } 

        } 
    }

    for(int i=0; i< matrix[0].length; i++) 
   { 

      for(int j=0; j< 
       matrix[i].length;j++) 
    {
       System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
    }
System.out.println();

    } 

}


}
```

Cabe señalar que , esta solución no es tan eficiente con las otras.

**PROPUESTA ORIGINAL**

Esta es una solución con Java 8. Básicamente realiza lo siguiente:

1. Selecciono los ceros de cada fila y los pongo en vector.
2. Selecciono los números de cada fila y los pongo en otro vector.
3. Junto los vectores anteriores en cada fila de la matriz resultado.

Cabe señalar que, el resultado de cada selección o filtro es un vector con los valores encontrados.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[][] matrix={{5,0,0,5},{0,0,6,5},{0,5,5,0},{0,0,0,5}};

        int[] ceros = null;
        int[] numeros = null;
        int[][] resultado = new int[4][4];
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
           ceros=Arrays.stream(matrix[i]).filter(n->n==0).toArray();       
           numeros=Arrays.stream(matrix[i])
                         .filter(n->n>0).toArray();

           System.arraycopy(ceros, 0, 
                             resultado[i],
                             0, ceros.length); 
           System.arraycopy(numeros, 0,
                             resultado[i],
                             ceros.length, numeros.length); 
        }
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            Arrays.stream(resultado[i])
                  .forEach(
                   n-> System.out.print(n + " "));

            System.out.println();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el metodo `sort` de la clase `Arrays` te simplifica mucho el problema.

```
public void compactar() {
    for (int[] row : matrix) {
        Arrays.sort(row);
    }
}
```

Hace lo que pides.